# Hover on implicit replies works inconsistently

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The all-new implicit replies functionality has a quirk.

Hovering over an @Jeff doesn't highlight the previous message

Hovering over an @JeffAtwood does.

I assumed that the difference was to do with incomplete names, but here are some other examples:

- @Benjol (full name): works
- @Richard (full name): doesn't work
- @Nick (partial name): doesn't work
- @NickCraver (full name): does work
- @Tree (full name): does work
- @AndyE'shead (full name): does work
- @Andy (partial name): **does** work!

(Started experimenting in Chat feedback, [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/54640?offset=120) - though that's not much help, because the hover isn't implemented in transcript yet...)

Comment: I think it's supposed to be that partial matches don't act as replies, at least, that's what I understood when I was flicking between the discussion and work.

Comment: this has been re-worked, if you care to re-try.

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong suspicion that it isn't working *there* because it is am ambiguous match... so there have probably been multiple "Nick"s in the discussion. Hence @Nick works as a *mention*, but it can't make it an **unambiguous** auto-reply.

Additionally: it will only do an *implicit* reply if the other person has spoken in the last 12 hours.

**However**; I also believe that there is a slight overlap here. For example, if two "Nick"s have been in the room, but only one has spoken recently, maybe that *should* assume it is the recent Nick. At the moment it will short-circuit as soon as it finds the two "Nick"s. I'll tidy that up.

Comment: It was the @Richard not working that I really didn't get.

Comment: @Benjol - assuming this is the chat feedback room (77), then there is only one richard involved (userid=67392) - but; had he spoken in the last 12 hours?

Comment: Yup, it was around the #54701 message, we were discussing it together.